# How would you wait for the fetch inside componentDidMount/componentWillMount before to redirect ? ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, higher-order-components

```
function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) {
 return (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => authed === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}}/>}
  />
 )
}
```

I borrowed the previous component and I would like to keep a state property like loggedIn and then update this component state after the fetch promise as I don't want to store a boolean property like `authed` anywhere. Also I'm new to react and react-router (V4) I practiced it for 3 weeks, thanks in advance !
I got this so far :

```
class AuthRoute extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {checking: true, loggedIn:false};
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('/sourcing/auth/loggedin',{credentials:'include', method:'POST'})
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(user => {
                console.log('user dans le fetch', user);
                if(user !== null)
                    this.setState({loggedIn: true, checking: false});
            })
    }

    render() {
        const {component , ...rest} = this.props;
        return(
            !this.state.checking && this.state.loggedin
                ? <DefaultLayoutRoute {...rest} component={component} />
                : <Redirect to='/login' />
        );
    }
}
```

The main problem is I set the state after that this component did unmount and I want a proper way to wait for the fetch without making a synchronous request

Comment: You want to keep state on `PrivateRoute`? If so, make it into a class with a `render` method. [The docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) are good.

Comment: thanks @TomFenech, I can read the doc, and I did, but I would like to transform this particular component into a class, and getting the same behavior, wich I don't have as I get errors

Comment: then update your question with what you've tried and what errors you are getting

Comment: OK, so there's the code, what's the problem?

Comment: @TomFenech Actually it works but the problem is the same, if I want to redirect to login after the fetch it actually never waits for the fetch to finish before to redirect (And I would love to use this component everywhere needed to auto redirect) I will update my question

Comment: @azium the error I get is that I try to set the state on a unmounted component as it redirect immediately without waiting for the fetch

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by just adding another test for the render method, I forgot to post my answer:

```
class AuthenticatedRoute extends React.Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {checking: true, loggedIn:false};
        this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
    }

    validate = (user, loggedIn , checking) => {
        storeUser(user);
        this.setState({loggedIn: loggedIn, checking: checking});
        if(loggedIn) console.log("loggedIn");
    } 

    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('/sourcing/auth/loggedin',{credentials:'include', method:'POST'})
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(user => {
                if(user){
                    this.validate(user, true ,false);
                }
                else
                    this.validate(null, false, false);
            })
            .catch(() => this.validate(null, false, false))
    }

    render() {
        const {component:Component , ...rest} = this.props;

        if(this.state.checking){
            return <DefaultLayoutRoute {...rest} component={() => <div>Loading...</div> } />
        }
        if(this.state.loggedIn){
           return <DefaultLayoutRoute {...rest} loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} component={Component} />
        }
        if(!this.state.checking && !this.state.loggedIn){
            return <Redirect to='/login' />
        }
    }
}
```